# GMSK transmission issues on GnuRadio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to implement rather simple scheme to transfer data from one sdr board to another. I'm using GnuRadio 3.7.14 and my scheme in companion looks like this

[image]

Source file is a binary of 96 bytes long and it looks like this

```
00000000  00 00 00 ff aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00000010  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00000020  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00000030  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060
```

At output I expect that after some noise there will be input pattern repeated (maybe with some errors), but in reality it looks like this

```
00004610  00 00 00 1f f5 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  |.....UUUUUUUUUUU|
00004620  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  53 63 eb ea aa a8 aa aa  |UUUUUUUUSc......|
00004630  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004640  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004650  80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004660  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88  |................|
00004670  80 00 00 7f d5 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  |.....UUUUUUUUUUU|
00004680  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 0d  0b a2 aa aa aa aa aa aa  |UUUUUUU.........|
00004690  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
000046a0  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
000046b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000046c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000046d0  00 00 01 ff 55 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 51  |....UUUUUUUUUUUQ|
000046e0  15 61 55 31 75 fc aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |.aU1u...........|
000046f0  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004700  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa a8  |................|
00004710  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004720  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004730  00 00 03 fe aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004740  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004750  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004760  aa aa 9a ac 6e 8a db 59  3c ae aa b8 aa ac aa a8  |....n..Y<.......|
00004770  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004780  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004790  00 00 07 fd 55 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  |....UUUUUUUUUUUU|
000047a0  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  55 45 55 55 55 55 5b 55  |UUUUUUUUUEUUUU[U|
000047b0  28 aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |(...............|
000047c0  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa a0  |................|
000047d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000047e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 40 20 00  |.............@ .|
000047f0  00 00 1f f5 55 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  |....UUUUUUUUUUUU|
00004800  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 64 ab aa  |UUUUUUUUUUUUUd..|
00004810  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004820  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 80  |................|
00004830  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004840  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004850  00 00 7f d5 55 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  |....UUUUUUUUUUUU|
00004860  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 6e  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |UUUUUUUn........|
00004870  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
00004880  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa a8 ab b3 54 00  |..............T.|
00004890  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000048a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000048b0  00 03 fe aa aa aa aa aa  aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa  |................|
000048c0  aa aa aa aa aa aa a8 5d  15 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  |.......].UUUUUUU|
000048d0  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  |UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU|
000048e0  55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55  55 55 41 56 b6 aa a0 00  |UUUUUUUUUUAV....|
000048f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00004900  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

I manually took this piece of output file, so it aligns close to input.
So, here I see two issues (which I believe have one cause):

- byte 0xAA (10101010b) switches to 0x55(01010101b) in some part of the message and vice versa
- beginning of the message is "sliding" out, there are a 8 bits difference between string 47f0 and 4610

The obvious reason for that is that receiver gets different amount of bits, than sender sends, but I doubt, what exactly leads to this behaviour? How can I debug this to find out what is going wrong?

A couple of words about my setup: I use 3 boards, one USRP B210, one Limesdr-USB and one Limesdr-Mini. I tried this experiment at least in 4 different combinations, including sending from the board to itself, and every time received same result. The boards seems to be ok, they successfully receive fm broadcast and transmit/receive sound by fm from one another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found similar question, and recipe given there works for me as well.
[GFSK demodulation with Xlating filter in GNU Radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251856/gfsk-demodulation-with-xlating-filter-in-gnu-radio)